# conditional sum with breaks

Tags: r, function, cumsum

I need to figure out how to continue with cumulative sum in `c` while there is true value in next four rows in `crit` from the row where it stooped.

Expected output is in the column `X`:

```
        crit c    X
    1     1   0   NA
    2     1   0   NA
    3     1   0   NA
    4     1   0   NA
    5     1   1    1
    6     1   2    2
    7     1   3    3
    8     1   4    4
    9     1   5    5
    10    1   6    6
    11    1   7    7   # end of curent cumsum in x
    12    0   0    NA
    13    0   0    NA
    14    0   0    NA
    15    1   0    8   # c rollsum should continue here 
    16    1   0    9   # because there weren't 4 rows with 0 in crit
    17    1   0    10
    18    0   0    NA
    19    1   0    11
    20    0   0    NA
    21    0   0    NA
    22    0   0    NA
    23    0   0    NA
    24    1   0    NA  # cumsum should stop as 4 rows have crit = 0
    25    1   0    NA
```

I don't have concrete code to show, because I have a whole bunch of attempts with, loops, `rle`, `ifelse`...

TRhe only way I can see this being solved is with function that would be add to ongoing cumsum in `c` to rows where `df$c[i<(i-1)]` and stop when conditions in there is more than 4 rows with 0 value in `crit`.

Data set:

```
    structure(list(crit = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), c = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), break_true = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), X = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, NA, NA, NA, 8, 9, 10, NA, 11, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("crit", "c", "break_true", "X"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In the last 2 rows, i.e. 24 and 25, your comment is that `# cumsum should continue as 4 rows have crit=1`, then why is the `X` coumn i.e. expected output NA there?

Comment: corrected it. It stops if four values of crit are 0.